# Sourcing a redistributable script by default

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, command-history

I am creating a bash script which I wish to release on github. The script needs to access the command history but this is not possible without sourcing that script.

I don't want users to put it in their `~/.bashrc` or source the script every time they run it.

So, is there any way I can create a script which gets sourced by default.

**Alternatively...**

Is there some way to access the history of the current terminal without sourcing the script?

Comment: If you don't want users to "source the script every time they run it", then when *do* you want them to source it? Once only right after they clone it from github? I'm not sure I understand, but I guess you could define a shell function which users invoke thereafter?

Answer (score 1):

If the script needs to access the history, insert an `alias` into the `.bashrc`. I have this for the command `auto` which has an option to repeat the latest command, ad infinitum, depending on changes in the provided commandline arguments.

The alias:

```
auto = 'history | auto'
```

Assuming that `some_command_to_test` depends on `input.py` and `output.py` I use this to first run the command once, then repeatedly (while changing `input.py` and `output.py` in some other window:

```
$ some_command_to_test arg1 arg2 arg3
$ auto -l input.py output.py
```

In the program (in my case `auto`) just read through the stdin to find the appropriate information ( I take the last command that doesn't involve `auto` itself, so I can stop `auto` and restart it without `auto`-ing `auto` itself).

This way there is no need to repeatedly source a script.